# Conditional input custom modifier with Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, modifiers

This may seem like an easy question, but i have tried a number of things, none which work.

I want to use a custom modifier in Store to show a color, and this code needs to be in a template, but not every item needs the color input, only the entry which needs it.

How would I wrap this in a conditional {if}{/if} so that it only appears when needed?

Many thanks in advance.

input:size="Color"

Green
  Yellow

Answer (score 2):

A conditional based on an entry's ID might look like this:

```
{exp:store:product}    
    {if entry_id == "XXX"}
            <select name="color">
                <option value="Green">Green</option>
                <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
            </select>
        {/if}
{/exp:store:product}
```

Replace XXX with the entry_id.